# Is it OK to use iostreams with int as character-type?

Tags: c++, iostream

When trying to come up with an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5496889/160206), I wrote this little test-program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void writeFile() {
    int data[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1000};

    std::basic_ofstream<int> file("test.data", std::ios::binary);
    std::copy(data, data+11, std::ostreambuf_iterator<int>(file));
}

void readFile() {
    std::basic_ifstream<int> file("test.data", std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<int> data(std::istreambuf_iterator<int>(file),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<int>()));

    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    writeFile();
    readFile();

    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected, writing the data to the file, and after reading the file, it correctly prints:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1000
```

However, I am not sure if there are any pitfalls (endianess issues aside, you always have these when dealing with binary data)? Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating any of the iostream classes, or basic_string, on anything
but char or wchar_t, without providing a specific custom traits class,
is undefined behavior; most of the libraries I've seen do define it to
do something, but that definition often isn't specified, and is
different between VC++ and g++ (the two cases I've looked at).  If you
define and use your own traits class, some of the functionality should
work.

For just about all of the formatted inserters and extractors (the `<<` and
`>>` operators), `istream` and `ostream` delegate to various facets in
the locale; if any of these are used, you'll have to take steps to
ensure that these work as well.  (This usually means providing a new
numpunct facet.)

Even if you only use the `streambuf` (as in your example), `filebuf`
uses the codecvt facet.  And an implementation isn't required to provide
a codecvt, and if it does, can do pretty much whatever it wants in
it.  And since `filebuf` always writes and reads `char` to and from the
file, this translation must do something.  I'm actually rather
surprised that your code worked, because of this.  But you still don't
know what was actually on the disk, which means you can't document it,
which means that you won't be able to read it sometime in the future.

If your goal is to write binary data, your first step should be to
define the binary format, then write read and write functions which
implement it.  Possibly using the iostream << and >> syntax, and
probably using a `basic_streambuf<char>` for the actual input and
output; a `basic_streambuf<char>` that you've carefully imbued with the
"C" locale.  Or rather than define your own binary format, just use an
existing one, like XDR.  (All of this paragraph supposes that you want
to keep the data, and read it later.  If these are just temporary files,
for spilling temporary internal data to disk during a single run, and
will be deleted at the end of the program execution, simpler solutions
are valid.)

Answer (score 4):

> It works as expected.

I'm not sure what you are expecting...

> Is this allowed?

That's probably not portable.  Streams relies on `char_traits` and on facets which are defined in the standard only for `char` and `wchar_t`. An implementation can provides more, but my bet would be that you are relying on a minimal default implementation of those templates and not on a conscious implementation for `int`.  I'd not be surprised that a more in depth use would  leads to problems.

Comment: Hm, that confirms my suspicion.

Comment: That means if I really want it, I could specialize `char_traits` for `int` myself.