# Copy data between streams of different type

Tags: c++, iostream

How can I effectively insert data from one stream into another stream of different type?

I have tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    basic_stringstream<unsigned short> uss;
    stringstream cs;

    unsigned short val = 0xffff;

    uss.write(&val, 1);            // write value to 'uss'

    uss.read(&val, 1);             // read data from 'uss' into 'val'
    cout << hex << val << endl;    // gives 0xffff

    cs << uss.rdbuf();             // copy 'uss' contents into 'cs'

    cs.read((char*) &val, 2);      // read data from 'cs' into 'val'
    cout << hex << val << endl;    // gives 0x3030 ?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497284/is-it-ok-to-use-iostreams-with-int-as-character-type

Comment: `cs << uss.rdbuf();` This line calls `operator<<(void*)`, and prints the pointer in hex as if by `printf("%p")`. I presume the address of `rdbuf()` pointer is of the form `00XXXXXX` when rendered in hex, hence 0x3030 (aka "00").

Answer (score 2):

First, as noted [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497284/is-it-ok-to-use-iostreams-with-int-as-character-type), you can't instantiate `basic_string`s and streams with types like `unsigned short` without writing a hell lot of custom template specializations.

Second, this line

```
cs << uss.rdbuf();
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `basic_ostream`'s `operator<<` that takes a `basic_streambuf` is

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<< (basic_streambuf<char_type,traits>* sb);
```

where `char_type` is a typedef for `charT`. In other words, the character types must match.

In your case, they don't match, so you end up calling `operator<<(const void *)` instead, and just printing out the address. When I tested this on coliru, it printed out `7830` instead, for the characters `0x`.